# how to add lookbook in laravel slider image

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I want to add a Lookbook on the slider's image where users can visit that particular product by clicking on that Lookbook icon. If the image has multiple products available so admin has to add multiple links to the product while adding the slider image.
I am looking for any library available on the internet for Laravel.
For reference I am sharing, that is something I want to implement.

[Image for reference](https://storecdn.webkul.com/wysiwyg/M2-LookBook/creating-lookbook-products.png)